# How to get id from concatenation of string in loop

Tags: apex, salesforce-id, string, record, casting

I am looping trough some records and want to get the related id. This works fine as `invoice.BillingAccount__r.BillToId__c`. In my case BillToId__c is a field that I get from a custom metadata setting. I tried it as a string but this is not working as:

```
string custMet = 'BillToId__c';
string idstr = invoice.BillingAccount__r + '.' + custMet;
```

I end up with the string: `invoice.BillingAccount__r.custMet`.

How can I get the value as Id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you're looking for is:

```
String custMet = 'BillToId__c';
String idStr = (String)invoice.getSObject('BillingAccount__r').get(custMet);
```

`getSObject` returns the instance of the related SObject.

As mentioned in the comments, `getSObject` is redundant here, but can be useful if you don't know the relationship name upfront.

```
String idStr = (String)invoice.BillingAccount__r.get(custMet);
```

This should work as well.